# Copiar parte do Dataframe onde coluna é Nulo ou NaN

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Estou com a seguinte dúvida.

Tenho o seguinte dataframe de exemplo:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [4,5,13,18], 'B' : [10,np.nan,np.nan,40], 'C' : [np.nan,50,25,np.nan], 'D' : [-30,-50,10,16], 'E' : [-40,-50,7,12]})
```

***df***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Oque pretendo fazer é:

- A partir da coluna B quero verificar em quais linha a coluna B é **'NAN'** e caso seja, quero criar um outro dataframe contendo as mesmas colunas do atual (df), porém somente com as linhas de índice 1 e 2 (nesse caso).

Para exemplificar melhor, o resultador deveria ser:

***df2***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei inicialmente utilizar o comando *loc*

```
df2 = df.loc[:]
```

porém, não consegui referência de como só buscar os valores *np.Nan*, existe alguma maneira de fazer isso?

Testei com os campos  nulo do pandas para ver o resultado.

```
    import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [4,5,13,18], 'B' : [10,'','',40], 'C' : ['',50,25,''], 'D' : [-30,-50,10,16], 'E' : [-40,-50,7,12]})
```

E utilizando a sintaxe:

```
df2 = df[pd.isnull(df).any(axis=1)]
```

esse comando funciona porém busca linhas em branco em qualquer coluna, como poderia mudar ele para pegar uma unica coluna?

Comment: não conheço muito o numpy, mas achei uma pergunta que pode te ajudar, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736590/fast-check-for-nan-in-numpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes utilizar uma das três opções:

```
op_a = df[df['B'].isnull()] # mesmo resultado com: isna()
# ou
op_b = df.loc[df['B'].isnull()] # mesmo resultado com: isna()
# ou
op_c = df.query('B != B')
```

ambas terá a saída:

```
   A    B     C   D   E
1  5  NaN  50.0 -50 -50
```

DataFrame utilizado como exemplo:

```
{
  'A' : [4,5,13,18],
  'B' : [10,np.nan,'',40],
  'C' : [np.nan,50,25,np.nan],
  'D' : [-30,-50,10,16],
  'E' : [-40,-50,7,12]
}
```

> Podes ser visto funcionando em [repl.it](https://repl.it/@wellmotta/pt-stackoverflow-345288)

Comment: Excelente! Funcionou muito bem obrigado. Só fiquei com uma dúvida, qual a diferença entre usar ou não o LOC?